# How to replace Jquery <div> to editable <textarea>?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to replace my Div tag to Editable textarea on button click("#Edit"). So that TextArea hold data present in Div tag in Editable format.


**Eg. Div**

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <table id="tab1">
    <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><%: Model.InfoName%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Last Name</td><td><%: Model.infoLastName%></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Fathers Name</td><td><%: Model.infoFatherName%></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Edit" id="button" />
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       $("#button").click(function () { $("#tabs-1")
// Here I need help to replace div tag to editable textarea(or form with editable textfields for every td with submit and cancel button) with one additional replacement which is replace Edit Button with Submit and cancel(two button)
       });
   });
```

**Need Solution for**::replace div tag to editable textarea with one additional replacement which is replace Edit Button with Submit and cancel(two button) so that i can submit changes i have done to some controller action.


**One possible Solution**:: to replace  to some other element (rendered element holding the same data which div hold but in editable format additionally it also hold Submit and Edit buttons)
What about this should i go for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <table id="tab1">
        <tr><td>First Name</td>
            <td><span id='name'><%: Model.InfoName%></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Last Name</td>
            <td><span id='lastName'><%: Model.infoLastName%></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Fathers Name</td>
            <td><span id='fatherName'><%: Model.infoFatherName%></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Edit" id="button" onclick="return button_onclick()" />
</div>
```

and script goes like this

```
$(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $("#name").replaceWith($('<input type=text>').attr({ id: 'name', value: $('#name').text() }));
        $("#lastName").replaceWith($('<input type=text>').attr({ id: 'lastName', value: $('#lastName').text() }));
        $("#fatherName").replaceWith($('<input type=text>').attr({ id: 'fatherName', value: $('#fatherName').text()}));
        $("#button").replaceWith($('<input type=Submit>').attr({ id: 'submit'}));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The term to Google for is "edit in place". You can use [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) Edit In Place Plugin For jQuery. There's a [demo page](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html) to see if it can do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tabs-1").replaceWith(function() {
  return "<textarea>" + this.innerHTML + "</textarea>";
});
```

Comment: Peter InnerHtml i'll display all html code (along with tags) i think

Comment: @Gimmebrkk I assumed that's what you wanted. If it's not, what do you want to display in the textarea?

Comment: Peter my main objective is to replace div with editable view(onclick Edit button) and submit editable fields to some controller action (on click submit button)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7DdKf/1/
You can listen on the 'click' event for the div and use jQuery's replace function to swap out your `<div>` (or any other HTML element) with a `<textarea>`

.